# Get Keychain statistics

Tags: ios, keychain

Is it possible to get Apple Keychain statistics as they are there for Chrome's smart lock?

I'm looking for something similar to what is available at this page (if you use Chrome): https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

Comment: Do you mean 'Keychain'?

Comment: I've presumed you meant Keychain — feel free to [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keychain Access (available from /Applications/Utilities/), select a keychain, choose a category and observe the number of items shown in the status bar.

[image]

You can't obtain any statistics about your keychain on iOS.

Comment: Sad that it's not working from inside ios... but thanks for the solution